# Implement a secure communication mechanism between the smart contract and the client."

Tags: security, cryptography, whisper

I'm developing a dapp to allow users to chat with each other. The problem is that I need to ensure the security of the transmitted messages. What mechanism can be used to make the communication between the smart contract and users secure? Additionally, since the state of the smart contract is visible to everyone, how can I save conversations in a way that they cannot be seen by anyone?

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers the question!